# A day without food safety questions

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that today -- Wednesday October 24th, 2018 -- when I opened up "new questions", there were the usual 25 most recent questions on the page, and *not one* of them was about food safety or spoilage.

Wow!

Congrats everyone who worked on encouraging other types of questions!